# How to fix IndexError: list index out of range proxy

Tags: python

I have a script here for free proxys but now it has an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "proxi.py", line 14, in

if (td[6].text=="no"): # If you change "no" to "yes" you get https

IndexError: list index out of range

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

out = ""
urls = ["http://www.us-proxy.org/","http://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html","http://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html"]
for url in urls:
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
tr = soup.find_all("tr")
for t in tr:
td = t.find_all("td")
if (td):
  if (td[6].text=="no"): # If you change "no" to "yes" you get https
    out+=(td[0].text+":"+td[1].text+"\n")
f = open("proxy.txt", "w")
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Please post your full error traceback as well and provide a working example.

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: check the length of td before you refer to `td[6]`

Comment: `IndexError` means you are doing this `someIterable[someIndex]` and `someIterable` doesn't have a value at `someIndex`. Check the the length before trying to access that index, or `try/except` the `IndexError`

Comment: I added the whole error. How can I check the length?

Answer (score 1):

td does not always have an index at spot 6

So when you do td[6] it will give you a index error

Look in this code where I print out the length of td
https://onlinegdb.com/BkcnRSZgr

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

out = ""
urls = ["http://www.us-proxy.org/","http://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html","http://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html"]
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    tr = soup.find_all("tr")
for t in tr:
    td = t.find_all("td")
    print(len(td))
    if (td):
        if (td[6].text=="yes"): # If you change "no" to "yes" you get https
            out+=(td[0].text+":"+td[1].text+"\n")
f = open("proxy.txt", "w")
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

Here is a example I made of what is happening.
https://onlinegdb.com/HJIXlL-xH

Hopefully it will help you understand better.

Comment: I do not really understand it, I have the following issue with your code : 0 8 8 8 8 etc 8 8 .. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxi2.py", line 15, in <module>
    if (td[6].text=="yes"): # If you change "no" to "yes" you get https
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

These URLs share a similar markup structure:

```py
urls = ["http://www.us-proxy.org/","http://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html","http://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html"]
```

There is a table with id `proxylisttable` containing the list of proxies with a header row and footer row.

I suggest to limit `tr` selection to this table e.g.

```py
trs = bs.select("table#proxylisttable tr")
proxies = trs[1:-1] # exclude heading and footer
```

Comment: In which line do I include this?